# Use built-in iMac camera on display connected via Thunderbolt

Tags: display, imac, camera, thunderbolt-display, target-display

I've got a 27" iMac connected via Thunderbolt using Target Display Mode. It all works fine. I am wondering if there is a way (hack or otherwise) to activate and use the built-in camera from the iMac from the Mac Pro (which is the main computer I am using).

From [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204592):

> A Mac that's connected to an iMac in Target Display Mode can't use the iMac computer's built-in camera, ...

So it seems that's a no, but I am hoping there may be a work around, so I don't have to purchase a separate camera.

Comment: It's not a two way connection.  Target Display Mode is *sending* video signals.  The camera is attached to the USB bus and you cannot access any USB device on the target display.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. Thanks for the explanation.